# Find Distance within each Raster contiguous cell block

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, distance, spatial-analyst

I was asked to find for each Individual Contiguous Forest Block the distances INSIDE of each where it would be the farthest (aka the most isolated) from each forest cell block's respective edges. I know this should involve Euclidean Distance and possibly followed by Reclassify, but perhaps not?
 I tried performing EucDist on the forest cell block layer with a mask of that same forest cell block layer, but the result didn't seem to be what I wanted.

[image: Image of individual forest cell blocks that are all > 1000cells]

Answer (score 1):

you could start reclassifying your input raster with a value of 1 for the background and NoData for your forest block. Either with reclassify tool or something like below in the raster calculator

```
Con("raster" == backgroundvalue, 1)
```

or (if your background is NoData)

```
Con(IsNull("raster"), 1)
```

Then you use zonal stat (maximum) based on each forest block

Finally, you look at the pixels where the maximum of the zonal stat is equal to the euclidian distance : those pixels are the farthest from edges.

Comment: in the first step are you saying to reclassify the input raster of each indivdual forest block, or reclass a eucdist raster?

Comment: I assumed you have only one raster (see my update) as I see only one raster in the TOC. I also assumed that each forest block has an unique value and that they are never adjacent.

Comment: Correct assumption...I finshed the second step and have a max zonal value of 255, but help me to better understand your third step.